# How to create a string array and append data from []net.ip

Tags: go

I have just created a function that taken an address in input resolve the ipv4 and ipv6, so the array that contains those ip addresses is of `[]net.ip` type. 
So I have two questions:

1- Is there any way to create a `[]string` array and copy each value of the `[]net.ip` array to `[]string` array

2- Will be possible later to add data to the `[]string` array?

thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use `IP.String()` to convert an IP to a `string`. What have you tried? What problems do you have?

Comment: i simply tried to cast all the array, so how can i convert all the array? i think i should go through each value and than use IP.string?

Comment: Yes, you have to use a loop, and handle each individually.

Comment: can you show me how would you do that? when I use `IP.string` it says me `undefined: IP`

Comment: Please check my first comment, and copy my code exactly. `IP.String()` is a method of the `net.IP` type. If you're not clear with the basics and syntax, please take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) first.

Comment: "tried to cast all the array" There _are_ no casts in Go and a slice is not an array. Take the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an utility function to do this as follow:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)


func transformIPArray(ipArray []net.IP) []string {
        s := make([]string,0)
    for _, ip := range ipArray {
        s = append(s, ip.String())
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
       #Get []string from []net.IP
       ip1 := net.ParseIP("192.100.10.4")
       ip2 := net.ParseIP("192.100.10.5")
       ips := []net.IP{ip1,ip2}
       s := transformIPArray(ips)
       fmt.Println(s)

       #Add new IP to the string array
       ip3 := net.ParseIP("192.100.10.6")
       s = append(s, ip3.String())
       fmt.Println(s)
}
```

You can check this code directly here: https://play.golang.org/p/9T0ejuvu-HA